# An error in Code blocks C++

Tags: c++, string, initialization

Why does Code blocks show me the error

> error: in C++98 'pro' must be initialized by constructor, not by '{...}'|

When I use `std::string pro{'A','B','C','D','E','F'};`?

How can I fix this?

Comment: Because you are using an outdated compiler (or at least not turning on C++11 support)

Comment: you are right but I tried it, unfortunately it shows the  Error too.

Comment: i will check it.

Comment: Rather than getting hung up on using an initializer list, why not initialize it to `"ABCDEF"`?

Comment: but this version of Code Blocks is developed last year.

Comment: You are using an old compiler, use `std::string pro1("ABCDEF");` instead of `std::string pro{ 'A','B','C','D','E','F' };`

Answer (score 1):

You are using C++ 98 standards and it doesn't support `{ }` initialization.

You have two options...

1. use `-std=c++0x` flag while compiling to use newer C++ standards.
2. Do initialization in the constructor or somewhere else.